# How can I check against a boxes background color...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a game for my computing class where a player moves round a grid and depending on their settings and the terrain they move on their playerPower should decrease differently.

When the player moves I need to check what colour the box they land on is in order to determine the amount of power to deduct. I can't seem to fathom out how to do it.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nZ8vA/

The comments: `//HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO CHECK THE COLOUR` is where I need to check the boxes colour when the player moves onto it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest keeping track of the player's position with a separate variable, since it's much easier/quicker to access a JavaScript variable than trying to derive it from CSS positioning, and figuring out background colours from the DOM itself. Anyways, here's a quick solution I threw together, which I think gives you what you want:

I added this variable to track player position:

```
// x, y coordinates of player
var playerPos = [0, 0];
```

Then, to check colours, I took advantage of your previously defined `map` array, which gives the colours of each map cell. I wrote a little function that takes two coordinates, and feeds them into the map array to get back the colour. Using a switch/case after that allows you to respond to each colour accordingly:

```
// Checks colour against predefined map
function checkCol(cell, row){
    var color = map[row][cell];

    switch (color){
        // Brown
        case "b":
            break;
        // Green
        case "g":
            break;
        // White   
        case "w":
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Lastly, with each key press, the coordinates of the player position are updated. One way to do it (while keeping within bounds of the map) is like so (note that each of these must be placed separately in your code, under the corresponding case during a key press):

```
// Left
playerPos[0] = Math.max(0, playerPos[0] - 1);

// Up
playerPos[1] = Math.max(0, playerPos[1] - 1);

// Right (you didn't specify you wanted this in your code with a comment, so just omit it if you don't want it)
playerPos[0] = Math.min(map[0].length - 1, playerPos[0] + 1);

// Down
playerPos[1] = Math.min(map.length - 1, playerPos[1] + 1);

// After each case, just call this to check the colour at the given position:
checkCol(playerPos[0], playerPos[1]);
```

This solution keeps all the logic within the JavaScript, and doesn't need to check the CSS of any elements.

Here's an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nZ8vA/2/) to show you the code implemented. Check the console using web developer tools, in case you want to verify it is returning the correct colours.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.